# speed up numpy array assignment

Tags: python, numpy

I have a function of the following structure. It basically computes the upper triangle of a matrix and makes it symmetric. Is it possible to make it faster using some numpy tricks?

```
import numpy as np

def g(x, y):
    # some calculation that returns a float

def f(a):
    """
    a is a list of objects, return a symmetric Numpy array
    """
    n = len(a)
    ret = np.empty((n,n))
    for i in range(1, n):
        for j in range(i+1, n):
            ret[i, j] = ret[j, i] = g(a[i], a[j])
```

Further details:
Here `a` is a list of objects (trajectory frames) that contains Nx3 numpy array (position of particles) as property and only this Nx3 numpy array is relevant to the calculation. Thus for simplicity, we can assume `a` is a list of the numpy arrays. `g` only uses numpy operations for the calculation. For example, it can be considered as geometric alignment and then average distance calculation.

Comment: As long as `g` is just 'some calculation' and `a` some objects, this is the best you can do.  Fast `numpy` has to use the compiled operations like whole-array multiplication, addition, and assignment.  If you can use those, trying exploit the symmetry isn't worth any extra effort.

Comment: Please provide some more informations. Is g a simple python function (with which dependencies,maybe only numpy?) Can you give an example what a actually is? Depending on this information you can probably speed the calculation up by more than an order of magnitude (with Numba, or Cython), or your solution is already the best you can do within Python.